# How to use Bless Operator in Perl?

Tags: perl, bless

can anyone please explain the importance and how to use bless in perl.
I have read many threads on stack overflow on bless but they are not clear.

Answer (score 7):

This is a way to make Perl treat packages as object oriented classes, and the blessed objects as instances of those classes.

Blessing a reference marks it so that the interpreter knows what package it is associated with. For example, if you write:

```
$x = {}; bless $x, "somepackage";
```

Then you can later write:

```
$x->method(1, 2, 3);
```

And the interpreter will treat this as:

```
somepackage::method($x, 1, 2, 3);
```

Here's a real simple example. Create a class in a file called MyClass.pm:

```
package MyClass;

sub new {
   my ($class_name) = @_;
   my $new_instance = {};
   bless $new_instance, $class_name;
   return $new_instance;
}

sub set {
   my ($self, $name, $value) = @_;
   $self->{$name} = $value;
}

sub get {
   my ($self, $name) = @_;
   return $self->{$name};
}
```

Now you can use the class in your code:

```
import MyClass;

my $instance = MyClass->new; # Same as MyClass::new("MyClass")
$instance->set('age', 30);   # Same as MyClass::set($instance, 'age', 30)
print $instance->get('age'); # Same as MyClass::get($instance, 'age')
```

The arrow operator, combined with how bless binds a reference to a package name, gives you nice object-oriented syntax.

Comment: `s/scalar/reference/`. You can only bless references. To link arbitrary data structures to an object, `tie` can be used.

Comment: can we use the blessed object anywhere else in the program? Like i bless it in one subroutine and can i use it later in another subroutine?

Comment: @Rahul Reddy: Yes. `bless` alters the reference, not the variable, so wherever you access the same item (via a reference), it will be associated with the package. It is in fact a very simple and lightweight change to the referenced data, but also a cornerstone of OO in Perl.

Comment: Actually, you can bless any scalar, so you can bless a string or a number, not just a reference. But by far the most common and useful case is to bless a reference to a hash.

Comment: @Charles Engelke: That is not true: `perl -e '$x = 5; bless $x,"Foo";'` results in 
`Can't bless non-reference value at -e line 1.`  You can however bless references to things that are not hashes.

Comment: @NeilSlater: You're absolutely right, my statement is wrong. I'm going to leave my comment because your comment adds value.

Answer (score 2):

The very top of the [perlobj documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#An-Object-is-Simply-a-Data-Structure) gives a helpful explanation with examples.

> #### An Object is Simply a Data Structure
>
> Unlike many other languages which support object orientation, Perl
>   does not provide any special syntax for constructing an object.
>   Objects are merely Perl data structures (hashes, arrays, scalars,
>   filehandles, etc.) that have been explicitly associated with a
>   particular class.
>
> That explicit association is created by the built-in [`bless`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) function,
>   which is typically used within the constructor subroutine of the
>   class.
>
> Here is a simple constructor:
>
> ```
> package File;
>
> sub new {
>     my $class = shift;
>
>     return bless {}, $class;
> }
> ```
>
> The name `new` isn't special. We could name our constructor something
>   else:
>
> ```
> package File;
>
> sub load {
>     my $class = shift;
>     return bless {}, $class;
> }
> ```
>
> The modern convention for OO modules is to always use new as the name
>   for the constructor, but there is no requirement to do so. Any
>   subroutine that blesses a data structure into a class is a valid
>   constructor in Perl.
>
> In the previous examples, the `{}` code creates a reference to an empty
>   anonymous hash. The bless function then takes that reference and
>   associates the hash with the class in `$class`. In the simplest case,
>   the `$class` variable will end up containing the string `"File"`.
>
> We can also use a variable to store a reference to the data structure
>   that is being blessed as our object:
>
> ```
> sub new {
>     my $class = shift;
>
>     my $self = {};
>     bless $self, $class;
>
>     return $self;
> }
> ```
>
> Once we’ve blessed the hash referred to by `$self` we can start calling
>   methods on it.

Answer (score 1):

`bless` is an older way to construct objects in Perl. For new code, I would recommend using [Moose](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose), [Moo](https://metacpan.org/module/Moo), or [Object::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Object%3a%3aTiny) instead.

Those are options are ordered from the largest in size and complexity (Moose) to the simplest with least features (Object::Tiny).

If you see `bless` in other perl code, it works as the other answers describe.

Comment: I’m sorry, but this really is not a reasonable statement. A lot of us work in places where we have to run with what the vendor gives us and little else. Those are not standard.

Comment: It is as least as reasonable as your work place rules, it seems.